# How to detect what cause empty/blank pages printed from web page

Tags: css, printing

I'm working on printing product web page. Employ `@media print {...}` to customize components for proper appearance on print canvas. But one issue I even can't understand how to drill to the root of the problem. The issue is that 3 out of 5 total pages are blank. First two pages rendered with content and then three blank pages. Chrome print preview popup window just give result and I have no clue what component(s) responsible for "printing" blank pages.

Answer (score 0):

I find how to use chrome devtool to emulate print canvas and drill down to trouble maker

[image]